# Powershell Out-File not working as expected with a reversed string

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need to write a file backwards line by line to another file. I can get it to work fine in the PowerShell window, but when I try to pipe it to an `Out-File`, it doesn't work. This is my script:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\files.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $text = $_.toCharArray()
    [Array]::Reverse($text)
    -join $text | Out-File 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reversed.txt'
}
```

This actually creates a file on the Desktop, but doesn't give it any content.

If I simply don't pipe to `Out-File` on the last line, it works fine, and prints the reversed file straight to the PowerShell window.

I have tried it with and without the single quotes, as well as using the `-FilePath` option. Nothing's working. Any ideas out there?

Comment: I'm thinking you have that `| Out-File` in the wrong place. Try it after the closing `}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the -Append parameter is not used, Out-File will overwrite the file each time it processes a line from the source file.  I suspect the last line of the source file is an empty line which is why you see nothing in the output file.

The proper way to do this is as @TheMadTechnician suggests:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\files.txt | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $text = $_.toCharArray()
        [Array]::Reverse($text)
        -join $text
    } | 
    Out-File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reversed.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. While I was driving across California today, this solution actually came to me... I'll definitely implement this when I get back to the office to see if it works... I'm quite certain that it will.

Comment: Verified. Works. Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried this on a file with `I like .` and it becomes garbled like so: `I like ºŸð.` Is there any way around that?